# Should we allow deletion of conflicted questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Deletion seems like it is something of an extreme action. If the community is in conflict over a question, should it be allowed to deleted?

For example:

- A question is posted, quickly gets +4/-10 downvotes
- Is closed relatively quickly
- Over time, garners 4 reopen votes
- Is summarily deleted by 20K+ users (45 minutes after original post)
- Has some, spirited, discussion prior to this between several high-rep users as to the quality of the question

At the moment, it has 2 undelete votes, a further indication that the viability of the question is in conflict. Given that *some* users seem to think the question is valuable/answerable and others not, should deletion be allowed?

I ask because while monitoring it, it feels as if the question was "pulled out from under" the community. One more reopen vote and it wouldn't have been deletable, so should we allow time for the community to decide?

Note that I am not asking for a discourse on the merits of this particular question, and would like to avoid the meta effect (as I have an answer on it and so have a conflict of interest). The described post is simply a good example of the situation I am trying to describe.

If you really want to see it here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066334/what-is-the-logic-of-the-main/26066384

Comment: Seems like a good idea, disallow deletion of a post that has more than x reopen votes? To me, if a question has, say, 3 reopen votes, it clearly must not be a question so terrible it needs to be deleted.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not it should be allowed.  Everyone will have an opinion on that, and it's always going to be a case by case business.  In this case, the appropriate course of action is to flag the question for moderator attention. If we feel the need to step in, we will. Since the moderator queue is backed up, you'll probably want to link to it on Meta, even with the meta effect in force; as we may not see it in a timely fashion in the moderator queue.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Put what is going on, why you think we should intervene, and what you think we should do. Be brief, but complete; especially with the action you want us to take and why.

Comment: Deleted by Eric Lippert. Sorry, that's out of my league.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Done and done. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those situations that should be brought up to a moderator's attention immediately.

Flagging is is the way to go, and bringing it up on meta is good in instances where we may not see it if it's in the moderator queue (currently, we have **a lot** of active flags in our queue).

When you flag it, remember the following:

1. Tell us why you're flagging it.
2. Tell us what you want us to do.
3. Tell us why you want us to do it.

Example:

> I'm flagging this because Smedley Dunlap keeps derailing the conversation, causing it to be deleted. Please undelete, as it does not meet the criteria for deletion.

In this partcular case, the question had several issues surrounding it; very few of which had to do with the actual question (most of it was the discussion in the comments).  Flagging or bringing up on Meta is the quickest way for us to respond to these situations.  You can also super-ping us @GeorgeStocker if you want to let us know without worrying about the Meta effect.

The super-ping works for all Stack Overflow moderators as well as Community Managers.

Comment: Do you mean super-pinging moderators works everywhere with a single at-sign? I thought it was two.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's hard for me to keep up; I was always under the impression it was a single @ sign.

Comment: All the references I can find are on the über-meta and of the form `@@<userid>@<sitename>`, so I wouldn't know :)

Comment: Only moderators can super ping.. (adding this here because people are referring to this post as a method of getting in touch with a moderator)