# Is there a preferred method of notifying moderators of posts when nothing is wrong?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators

Recently, I asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274888/2479481) on meta asking for a moderator to add some "version specific" tag synonyms.

The community seems to agree with my evaluation, based on upvotes; however, it doesn't seem like any moderators have taken notice of the question.

I *could* flag the question for moderator attention, but there's nothing really *wrong* with the question, so this seems like a subpar solution.

In the future, should I flag questions like these if they don't receive a moderator's attention, or is there a better way?

Comment: A moderator once mentioned they can be "super-pinged" if you want one of them to be aware of something without resorting to a flag (or triggering the Meta effect) in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272266/464709). Never tried it myself, though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi huh, I tried super pinging with a few different syntaxes, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Ah. Maybe George could not keep up after all ;) This feature may even warrant its own question (but yours seems appropriate enough for now).

Comment: You can notify moderators that "nothing is wrong" by raising a custom flag and putting "nothing is wrong" in the text box. I doubt it would be well received, but you can try.

Comment: @Louis *experiments, braces for spankings*

Comment: @Louis flagged comment: 'Nothing is wrong with this comment.'. *also braces for spankings*

Comment: Flag declined o_O

Comment: Hmm this is now featured... I'm pretty sure mods have seen this... Just wondering why they are silent..! come out guys, we won't bite!

Comment: @Louis **Nothing is wrong. – Jason C Nov 13 at 18:06   declined**. But they *didn't* say there was no evidence to support it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I raised this flag on my question:

> There's nothing wrong with the question--the requested task requires a moderator (apologies if a flag is inappropriate here).

And received this response:

> declined - Not sure why you put in this flag. No one said there was anything wrong.

However, the task *did* [get handled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274888/2479481#comment117725_274888):

> I've proposed them as synonyms now which should let the normal synonym voting process happen.
>
> -Flexo♦

---

So, I'd guess that **flagging is inappropriate for getting moderator attention**. Chat is probably more appropriate.

However, it *does* seem to work.

---

Also, you can vote on [these synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/multidimensional-array/synonyms) if you have 2500+ rep and a score of 5+ in [multidimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array).

Answer (score 3):

### What you can do

flag as other

### What you should do

Nothing. If you have posted a question then they are capable of seeing it, just like everyone else. If the moderators/community feels strongly about it then it will be addressed.

Answer (score -2):

With everything that happens in SO, I think moderators are some really busy people. Furthermore, [you can create tag synonyms when you have 2500+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) (which you do) - so I think calling their attention to this is not necessary.

**Edit:** as per the comments, it seems like version specific synonyms can only be applied by moderators.

If that is the case, then I do think calling their attention is OK. I also think that the privileges help section should be updated to include that information.

Comment: You are correct that I have permission to add tag synonyms, but because the system thinks the synonyms I'm trying to add are "version specific," adding them requires a moderator.

Comment: @LukeWillis You could also just go into a chat room and see if one is hanging out; often they are. SO has plenty, and there's also always http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta